# Netlogo web extension "expected a literal value"

Tags: list, netlogo

I have a model which is meant to interact with an api using web extension. So after each move, I will send my current location, heading to the API.

This is the code I am using:

```
to follow-path
  let choice web:make-request "http://127.0.0.1:8000/predict_get" "GET" [] []
  (ifelse
    choice = 0 [
      forward 1
    ]
    choice = 1 [
      right 90
    ]
    choice = 2 [
      left 90
    ]
    ; elsecommands
    [
      stop
  ])
  let data web:make-request "http://127.0.0.1:8000/netlogo" "POST" [["data" (list xcor ycor heading)]] []
end

to move-agent
  ask turtle (count turtles - 1) [follow-path]
end
```

Then when I checked, it said "Expected a literal value" at the list part. How can I post the list of data to the api correctly ?

Comment: this is answered in the NetLogo FAQ at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#im-trying-to-make-a-list-why-do-i-keep-getting-the-error-expected-a-literal-value

Answer (score 1):

I think you are struggling with the `[[ ]]` notation in NetLogo. This notation allows creating lists with only actual values but doesn't work with variables.

I recommend you to test the following explanation in the Command Center for an illustration.

**Creating lists with just values:**

The following code: `show [ [ "name" "john"] ["surname" "doe"] ]`

Would print the following outcome: `[["name" "john"] ["surname" "doe"]]`

This way, you can create lists with *literal* values. However, you cannot use variables instead of literal values. For example, the following code would give the same error you are seeing in your code:

```
let name "john"
let surname "doe"
show [ [ "name" name] ["surname" surname] ]
```

**Creating lists with variables**

You should use the `list` primitive in a nested manner to create your arguments for the `web:make-request` command to solve your problam.

Here's an example usage:

```
let name "john"
let surname "doe"
show (list (list "name" name) (list "surname" surname))
```

which would print:

```
[["name" "john"] ["surname" "doe"]]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works in the command center. However when I try to do it with the web:make-request, it still asks for a literal value. This is my line of code let data web:make-request "http://127.0.0.1:8000/netlogo" "POST" [(list (list "x:" current-xcor) (list "y:" current-ycor) (list "heading:" myheading) (list "dest_x:" dest-xcor) (list "dest_y:" dest-ycor))] []

Comment: Hey there. You do not need the brackets `[]` for the third argument. the list primitive automatically generates those brackets. so, your third argument should be as follows: `(list (list ...) (list ...) (list ...) (list ...) (list ...))`. I omitted the actual arguments for sake of brevity but I hope it's not more confusing.